# jQuery - Dynamically Create Button and Attach Event Handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to dynamically add a button control to a table using jQuery and attach a click event handler. I tried the following, without success:

```
$("#myButton").click(function () {
    var test = $('<button>Test</button>').click(function () {
        alert('hi');
    });

    $("#nodeAttributeHeader").attr('style', 'display: table-row;');
    $("#addNodeTable tr:last").before('<tr><td>' + test.html() + '</td></tr>');
});
```

The above code successfully adds a new row, but it doesn't handle adding the button correctly. How would I accomplish this using jQuery?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Calling `.html()` serializes the element to a string, so all event handlers and other associated data is lost. Here's how I'd do it:

```
$("#myButton").click(function ()
{
    var test = $('<button/>',
    {
        text: 'Test',
        click: function () { alert('hi'); }
    });

    var parent = $('<tr><td></td></tr>').children().append(test).end();

    $("#addNodeTable tr:last").before(parent);
});
```

Or,

```
$("#myButton").click(function ()
{    
    var test = $('<button/>',
    {
        text: 'Test',
        click: function () { alert('hi'); }
    }).wrap('<tr><td></td></tr>').closest('tr');

    $("#addNodeTable tr:last").before(test);
});
```

If you don't like passing a map of properties to `$()`, you can instead use

```
$('<button/>')
    .text('Test')
    .click(function () { alert('hi'); });

// or

$('<button>Test</button>').click(function () { alert('hi'); });
```

Comment: FWIW, I don't like the way you've done `click` as an extension to the element creation - I think `.click()` is more intuitive, and better documented.

Comment: Either way works just fine. I can show how do it with chaining as well.

Comment: it makes more sense now you've added the extra attributes

Answer (score 10):

Quick fix.
Create whole structure tr > td > button; then find button inside; attach event on it; end filtering of chain and at the and insert it into dom.

```
$("#myButton").click(function () {
    var test = $('<tr><td><button>Test</button></td></tr>').find('button').click(function () {
        alert('hi');
    }).end();

    $("#nodeAttributeHeader").attr('style', 'display: table-row;');
    $("#addNodeTable tr:last").before(test);
});
```

Comment: there's no need to `.end()` that chain.

Comment: It is. find('button') will return just button element, but you need whole tr>td>button structure :)

Comment: ah - I see - to ensure that the returned value is the `<tr>` itself?  Useful :)

Comment: @Matt Ball: Why is a terminal `end()` ever necessary?

Comment: Oh, never mind.  It's only useless at the end if you don't care about the returned value.

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is that you're converting the button into an HTML snippet when you add it to the table, but that snippet *is not the same object* as the one that has the click handler on it.

```
$("#myButton").click(function () {
    var test = $('<button>Test</button>').click(function () {
        alert('hi');
    });

    $("#nodeAttributeHeader").css('display', 'table-row'); // NB: changed

    var tr = $('<tr>').insertBefore('#addNodeTable tr:last');
    var td = $('<td>').append(test).appendTo(tr);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use onclick inside the button to ensure the event is preserved, or else attach the button click handler by finding the button after it is inserted. The `test.html()` call will not serialize the event.

Answer (score 0):

You were just adding the html string. Not the element you created with a click event listener.

Try This:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="addNodeTable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Row 1
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td>
                Row 2
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var test = $('<button>Test</button>').click(function () {
            alert('hi');
        });
        $("#addNodeTable tr:last").append('<tr><td></td></tr>').find("td:last").append(test);

    });
</script>
```