# create a button in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make an event in jQuery that adds a "like" button every time I click a "create" button?

Currently I have only a "create" button and every time I click it I want a "like" button to be added to the page.

Comment: ???? have just seen a similar question a while ago..have you reposted with another id?

Comment: What have you tried? Where's your code? Have you done any searches at all to try to figure this out, or are you just hoping the community will do all the work for you?

Comment: So you are asking how to create an element in response to user interaction (a mouse click)? This should be covered by any jQuery tutorial. A quick [Google search](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=jquery+how+to+create+an+element+on+click) revealed: [Dynamically create elements with jQuery](http://www.morkalork.com/mork/article/130/How_to_dynamically_create_new_elements_using_jQuery.htm). Of course there is always [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/), especially http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Comment: I've downvoted you because your question: (1) is vague, (2) has already been asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205258/jquery-dynamically-create-button-and-attach-event-handler) and (3) you neglected to show any of your code or show us you have done any research on the problem and finally (4) googling your question, verbatim, provides TONS of answers.

Comment: PS: For many people who post here, their first posts don't get good reception and get tons of downvotes. Don't be discouraged, but DO check out the [FAQ for asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq/)

Comment: @user1042031 the OP has a `peer pressure` badge and given that the users account is new today.... probably.

Comment: @Eonasdan : Ok..letme +1 for OP not to disappoint freshers as kasapo was saying....@lean..check this link just for your start not a solution ..http://jsfiddle.net/WW2Wx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has a .append() method. Use this to add any text or markup to an element in you HTML document. Use this to add the necessary markup to create a new button on your page.

http://api.jquery.com/append/