# How to add a button dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My task is to add button dynamically to the div.. here is the code that i follow to add button dynamically but its not working please give me a solution for this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
         <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             function test() {
                var r = "$('<input/>').attr({
                             type: "button",
                             id: "field"
                        })";
             }
             $("body").append(r);
         </script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <button onclick="test()">Insert after</button> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

code to append button on div when page loads but its not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
function test() {
    var r=$('<input/>').attr({
        type: "button",
        id: "field"

    });
    test().append("#test");    
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test"></div>
 <button id="insertAfterBtn" onclick="test()">Insert after</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$("body").append(r);` needs to go IN the function.

Comment: Please refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6205324/3530081

Answer (score 57):

Your append line must be in your `test()` function

**EDIT:**

Here are two versions:

**Version 1: jQuery listener**

```
$(function(){
    $('button').on('click',function(){
        var r= $('<input type="button" value="new button"/>');
        $("body").append(r);
    });
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/SP8de/)**

**Version 2: With a function (like your example)**

```
function createInput(){
    var $input = $('<input type="button" value="new button" />');
    $input.appendTo($("body"));
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/RtD6YvSz2jGUiisTt3Ad?p=preview)**

Note: This one can be done with either `.appendTo` or with `.append`.

Comment: sorry i can't catch up wht u say

Comment: you should use your .append() function INSIDE of your test() function, because you want the new input to be appent to your body each time your click the button, it means each time your run your function, that's why you should put your line $("body").append(r); in your function instead of putting it after.

Answer (score 7):

To add dynamic button on the fly;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function newButtonClickListener() {
            alert("Hello World");
        }
        function test() {
            var r = $('<input/>').attr({
                type: "button",
                id: "field",
                value: "New Button",
                onclick: "newButtonClickListener()"
            });
            $("body").append(r);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="test()">Insert after</button><br/> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This would be more useful as a runnable snippet, that way anyone can see how it works immediately.

Answer (score 4):

the `$("body").append(r)` statement should be within the `test` function, also there was misplaced `"` in the `test` method

```
function test() {
    var r=$('<input/>').attr({
        type: "button",
        id: "field",
        value: 'new'
    });
    $("body").append(r);    
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e4WhE/)

**Update**
In that case try a more jQuery-ish solution

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          jQuery(function($){
              $('#mybutton').one('click', function(){
                  var r=$('<input/>').attr({
                      type: "button",
                      id: "field",
                      value: 'new'
                  });
                  $("body").append(r);   
              })
          })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="mybutton">Insert after</button> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UQL5Xa4yv6coCWIhmbyD?p=preview)

Comment: I want to be the first to thank you for making that code readable... It was *really* badly formatted

Comment: how can we add value to this button??

Comment: ok thanks.. how to append this button only "once" on a button click insertafter

Comment: and giv me a solution to append button on a div when the page load.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
function test() {
    var r=$('<input/>').attr({
        type: "button",
        id: "field"
       
    });
    test().append("#test");    
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test"></div>
 <button id="insertAfterBtn" onclick="test()">Insert after</button>
</body>
</html>

Comment: the above code that i have used to append button on a div when page loads but its not working

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function test()
{
    if($('input#field').length==0)
    {
       $('<input type="button" id="field"/>').appendTo('body');
     }
}
</script>
```

Comment: button should be appended only once how we can do this

Comment: @user2236221 check updated answer if input with id field is not exist than it append it to body other wise not..

Comment: how we can pass id, value etc through function like this_app.CreateButton (id, text, primaryIcon, secondaryIcon, className);

Answer (score -2):

Working plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PeLLXWI6XQHpIyoTQECQ?p=preview).

To add the new input just once, use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#insertAfterBtn").one("click", function(e)
  {
    var r = $('<input/>', { type: "button", id: "field", value: "I'm a button" });

    $("body").append(r);
  });
});
```

[... source stripped here ...]

```
<body>
    <button id="insertAfterBtn">Insert after</button>
</body>
```

[... source stripped here ...]

To make it work in w3 editor, copy/paste the code below into 'source code' section inside w3 editor and then hit 'Submit Code':

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button id="insertAfterBtn">Insert only one button after</button>
    <div class="myClass"></div>
    <div id="myId"></div>
  </body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
  // when dom is ready, call this method to add an input to 'body' tag.
  addInputTo($("body"));

  // when dom is ready, call this method to add an input to a div with class=myClass
  addInputTo($(".myClass"));

  // when dom is ready, call this method to add an input to a div with id=myId
  addInputTo($("#myId"));

  $("#insertAfterBtn").one("click", function(e)
  {
    var r = $('<input/>', { type: "button", id: "field", value: "I'm a button" });

    $("body").append(r);
  });
});

function addInputTo(container)
{
  var inputToAdd = $("<input/>", { type: "button", id: "field", value: "I was added on page load" });

  container.append(inputToAdd);
}
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: @user2236221 Have you checked that plunk? it's working fine on my side, clickin the button will add a new button each time. What browser are you using? Have you tried the code and it gave any errors?

Comment: please giv me a solution to append button on a div when the page loads

Comment: @user2236221 can I ask you why you're using w3 editor? Anyway, check my first answer, you don't need script.js :)

Comment: ur first ans is working fine but this code not working can u please give me script.js file.. what is included in that file

Comment: please let me know how to put an alert on this button click without changing the code

Comment: alert("my message here"); what do you mean by "put an alert on this button click without changing the code"? :-)

Comment: how we can pass id ,type etc as parameters in the function

Comment: how to change the above code like _app.CreateButton (id, text, primaryIcon, secondaryIcon, className); please help mee

Comment: the above code is for append only one button to a div if we want to append more than one button with different id to a div .. is there any solution for this by creating a simple function.???? please help me

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
function test()
{
   $("body").append("<input type='button' id='field' />");
}
```