# Add Remove table row using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I cannot delete the dynamically generated row in a table. I have searched the internet but couldn't found any suitable solution to my problem. I'm sharing what I have done so far:

```
$("#AddMore").click(function () {
    $("#maintable").each(function () {
        var tds = '<tr>';
        jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
            tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
        });
        tds += '</tr>';
        if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
            $('tbody', this).append(tds);
        } else {
            $(this).append(tds);
        }
    });
});
$("#maintable").on('click', "#deleteRow", function () {
    $("#deleteRow").closest('tr').remove();
});
```

This script is just adding rows but I can't delete the row. I have used jQuery remove function but didn't get any result. Please guide me

Comment: where is removing code?

Comment: provide your complete code ..

Comment: @EhsanSajjad i have editted my question u can check

Comment: You should look the jQuery doc for delegated events. In short, if you want to set event handler on dynamically created elements, you should actually link the event to the parent of those elements. It would be easier to help you seeing the HTML and whole javascript, which you can erasilly show us through a jsfiddle.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226598/how-to-add-a-button-dynamically-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mihgt want to change

```
$("#deleteRow").closest('tr').remove();
```

To

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all use **class** instead of **id** becuase id must be unique and then do like this:

```
$("#maintable").on('click', ".deleteRow", function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: i have used this and it solved the issue "$("#delete").click(function () {
    $('tr:last').remove();
});" no i want to ask that is there any way to display remove button only when new dynamic row added? not on page load

Comment: the way you are appendin tr you can append a button as well same way

Comment: i have a autocomplete textbox as well i also want to use autocomplete with dynamic textboxes, how can i do that?

Comment: on those textboxes add a class and write delegated event on class

Comment: i cannot append remove button can u show me how can i do that with code? this is the button "var btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="delete" class="btn yellow">Remove</a>';"